# "Your system is running in low graphics mode" error

Tags: 14.04, ati, fonts, lightdm, gdm

I'm quite new to ubuntu. I recently downloaded pycharm for python development. The fonts on the pycharm editor looked broken, so I was googling for a fix. I stumbled upon [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510099/ugly-fonts-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu) and tried out the last answer-

1. REQUIRED Remove openjdk and install oracle jdk.
2. Download deb from http://ppa.launchpad.net/no1wantdthisname/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig-infinality/
3. Install it: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. Enable osx font smoothing: `sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle`
5. Reboot your system `sudo reboot lightgdm`

After executing `sudo reboot lightgdm`, my laptop rebooted and now "Your system is running in low graphics mode" error is being displayed instead of the log-in screen. I can't pinpoint to what went wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can only hope that you have installed only one a deb file.

Comment: Yes, following that link, I installed this [deb file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/no1wantdthisname/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig-infinality/fontconfig-infinality_20130104-0ubuntu0ppa1_all.deb). Then executed the command stated on point 4, selected osx font smoothing from there.

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle`. =)

Comment: It says - Select a style : 1. Debug, 2. Infinality, 3. Linux, 4. Osx, 5. Osx2, 6. Win7, 7. Win98, 8. Winxp

Comment: The link in your comment is a dead link.

Comment: I can still access that link. I've uploaded that deb file on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qiTf19Yzj0Zk5QODFpdkdORnM/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for me was this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and this command

```
sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality
```

and a reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed `fontconfig-infinality` that and the problem is solved.

Comment: @user1362452 and my upvote? You have more than 15 points ;)

Comment: Yes upvoted it,  I had 13 points before. Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: Like cancer: cut it out!  **;-)**